# How to set variable FPS in libx264 and what encoder parameters to use?

Tags: c++, video, libx264

I'm trying to encode a webcam frames with libx264 in realtime, and face with one problem - the resulting video length is exactly what I set, but camera is delays somtimes and the real capture time is more than video length. As a result the picture in video changes to fast.
I think it is due to constant FPS in x264 settings, so I need to make it dynamic somehow. Is it possible? If I wrong about FPS, so what I need to do, to synchronize capturing and writing?

Also I would like to know what are the optimal encoder parameters for streaming via internet and for recording to disk (the client is streaming from camera or screen, and the server is recording)?

Here is console logs screenshot and my code:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include "stringf.h"
#include "Capture.h"
#include "x264.h"

int main( int argc, char **argv ){
    Camera instance;
    if(!instance.Enable(0)){printf("Camera not available\n");return 1;}
    // Initializing metrics and buffer of frame
    unsigned int width, height, size = instance.GetMetrics(width, height);
    unsigned char *data = (unsigned char *)malloc(size);
    // Setting encoder (I'm not sure about all parameters)
    x264_param_t param;
    x264_param_default_preset(&param, "ultrafast", "zerolatency");
    param.i_threads = 1;
    param.i_width = width;
    param.i_height = height;
    param.i_fps_num = 20;
    param.i_fps_den = 1;
    // Intra refres:
    param.i_keyint_max = 8;
    param.b_intra_refresh = 1;
    // Rate control:
    param.rc.i_rc_method = X264_RC_CRF;
    param.rc.f_rf_constant = 25;
    param.rc.f_rf_constant_max = 35;
    // For streaming:
    param.b_repeat_headers = 1;
    param.b_annexb = 1;

    x264_param_apply_profile(&param, "baseline");
    x264_t* encoder = x264_encoder_open(&param);

    int seconds, expected_time, operation_start, i_nals, frame_size, frames_count;
    expected_time = 1000/param.i_fps_num;
    operation_start = 0;
    seconds = 1;
    frames_count = param.i_fps_num * seconds;
    int *Timings = new int[frames_count];

    x264_picture_t pic_in, pic_out;
    x264_nal_t* nals;
    x264_picture_alloc(&pic_in, X264_CSP_I420, param.i_width, param.i_height);
    // Capture-Encode-Write loop
    for(int i = 0; i < frames_count; i++){
        operation_start = GetTickCount();
        size = instance.GrabBGR(&data);
        instance.BGRtoI420(data, &pic_in.img.plane[0], &pic_in.img.plane[1], &pic_in.img.plane[2], param.i_width, param.i_height);
        frame_size = x264_encoder_encode(encoder, &nals, &i_nals, &pic_in, &pic_out);
        if( frame_size > 0){
            stringf::WriteBufferToFile("test.h264",std::string(reinterpret_cast<char*>(nals->p_payload), frame_size),1);
        }
        Timings[i] = GetTickCount() - operation_start;
    }
    while( x264_encoder_delayed_frames( encoder ) ){ // Flush delayed frames
        frame_size = x264_encoder_encode(encoder, &nals, &i_nals, NULL, &pic_out);
        if( frame_size > 0 ){stringf::WriteBufferToFile("test.h264",std::string(reinterpret_cast<char*>(nals->p_payload), frame_size),1);}
    }
    unsigned int total_time = 0;
    printf("Expected operation time was %d ms per frame at %u FPS\n",expected_time, param.i_fps_num);
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < frames_count; i++){
        total_time += Timings[i];
        printf("Frame %u takes %d ms\n",(i+1), Timings[i]);
    }
    printf("Record takes %u ms\n",total_time);
    free(data);
    x264_encoder_close( encoder );
    x264_picture_clean( &pic_in );
    return 0;
}
```

[image: log_x264]
The capture takes 1453 ms and the output file plays exactly 1 sec.

So, in general, the video length must be the same as a capture time, but not as encoder "wants".
How to do it?

Comment: What is `Camera` please? Are you using some other library?

Comment: I am not sure what you are expecting - if you tell `libx264` to set a play rate of 25 fps and pass it 250 frames, you will get a 10 second long video, but if your camera takes 1/10 second to acquire each frame, it will take 25 seconds to acquire the necessary frames.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, `Camera` is my own wrapper on Windows native vfw32, but it does not matter, OpenCV gives same latency. You can see on screenshot, that the capture takes 1453 ms, and the video is 1 sec. I'm expecting the same length of video as a capture takes

Comment: @MarkSetchell, Also I'm not sure about parameters I use - for example what is `X264_RC_CRF`, `f_rf_constant` (I took this parameters block somewhere on SO)?

Comment: If you want to capture 25 frames in 1 second, you can a) improve the lighting (brighter) so your exposures are shorter, or b) accumulate the 25 frames in RAM and write to disk later aftee capture, or c) multithread your code, or some mixture.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, option b is most suitable for my purposes. Thanks for advice